# How to attach the onclick of a home icon in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have this test app with a single activity, who's layout has a `FrameLayout`.  There are 2 fragments, **MainDisplay.java** is programmatically loaded when the app starts and **AccountSetup.java** when the user clicks through menu and selects account setup.  Currently when the user goes to account setup the **AccountSetup.java** changes the menu to **menu_secondary.xml**, which features a main item that replaces the fragment with the starting fragment from layouts.  I have figured out how to add a "<" icon to the action bar whenever the **main_display.xml** is not occupying the spaced defined in activity_main.xml's `FrameLayout`. But I have not figured out how to register clicks on it, so it will reload the **main_display.xml** into framelayout of **activity_main.xml**. I appreciate any help in getting it to register clicks.

> MainActivity.java

```
package "";

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MiddleMan {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.activity_main_framelayout) != null) {
            if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            MainDisplay f = new MainDisplay();
            ShiftView(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_account_setup) {
            AccountSetup f = new AccountSetup();
            ShiftView(f);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.home) {
            System.out.println("Up button pressed");
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void ShiftView(Object obj) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_framelayout, (Fragment) obj);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void DisplayHome(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void RemoveHome() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

> MainDisplay.java

```
package "";

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainDisplay extends Fragment {
    MiddleMan mCallBack;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallBack = (MiddleMan) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement ReqestConnect");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_display, container, false);
        mCallBack.RemoveHome();
        return view;
    }
}
```

> AccountSetup.java

```
package "";

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AccountSetup extends Fragment {
    MiddleMan mCallBack;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallBack = (MiddleMan) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement ReqestConnect");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_setup, container, false);
        mCallBack.DisplayHome();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_secondary, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_main_display) {
            MainDisplay f = new MainDisplay();
            mCallBack.ShiftView(f);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.home) {
            System.out.println("Up button pressed, from setup");
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

> MiddleMan.java

```
package "";

public interface MiddleMan {
    void ShiftView(Object obj);
    void DisplayHome();
    void RemoveHome();
```

I also tried:

```
if (id == R.id.homeAsUp) {
            System.out.println("Up button pressed, from setup");
        }
```

No luck.

**Conclusion**

`id == android.R.id.home` was the key, ty to everyone who responded.

> MainActivity.java

```
package "";

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MiddleMan {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.activity_main_framelayout) != null) {
            if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            MainDisplay f = new MainDisplay();
            ShiftView(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_account_setup) {
            AccountSetup f = new AccountSetup();
            ShiftView(f);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            MainDisplay f = new MainDisplay();
            ShiftView(f);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void ShiftView(Object obj) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_framelayout, (Fragment) obj);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void DisplayHome(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void RemoveHome() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

> AccountSetup.java

```
package "";

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AccountSetup extends Fragment {
    MiddleMan mCallBack;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallBack = (MiddleMan) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement ReqestConnect");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_setup, container, false);
        mCallBack.DisplayHome();

        //setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return view;
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_secondary, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_main_display) {
            MainDisplay f = new MainDisplay();
            mCallBack.ShiftView(f);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
}
```

With that I don't need a second menu.xml for any "fragment views" and they can all return the user to the main page; the mainactivity retains control over the menu setup at all times, sans the home button, just what I was looking for. I didn't follow, the suggestion to add this behavior to onCreate, because I am only interested in having it displayed if the user is off the "main page," but I appreciate the effort, and maybe it will be something someone else is looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
 public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

int itemId = item.getItemId();
switch (itemId) {
case android.R.id.home:
    toggle();

    // Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;

}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
if (id == R.id.home) {
   System.out.println("Up button pressed");
 }
```

with

```
  if (id == android.R.id.home) {
     System.out.println("Up button pressed");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

please [see](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) this link.and kind change

```
 if (id == android.R.id.home) {

    System.out.println("Up button pressed");
  }
```

and please use this method and call this method in `onCreate()`

```
 private void actionBarSet() {
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```